# How to change renderValue in Mui React Select component to render another array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui

With a Material-UI Select component like this one, is there a way to customize `renderValue` to render an array of the `printname` key values from the corresponding dict?

I'm storing `lang.code` as values in the `paramvalues` array because i need them as URL parameters passed to a backend api call.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useNavigate, useLocation, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
    import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
    import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
    import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
    import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
    import Select from "@mui/material/Select";

    const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
    const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
    const MenuProps = {
    PaperProps: {
        style: {
        maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
        width: 250,
        },
    },
    };


    const MultipleSelectList = ({ cmpName, paramUrlName }) => {

        const arr = [
            {
                "code": "ita",
                "count": 184893,
                "printname": "Italian"
            },
            {
                "code": "eng",
                "count": 58135,
                "printname": "English"
            },
            {
                "code": "fre",
                "count": 36201,
                "printname": "French"
            }
            ]
    
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const params = {};
    searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
        params[key] = value;
    });
    
    function objectToQueryString(obj) {
        const keys = Object.keys(obj);
        const keyValuePairs = keys.map(key => {
        return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]);
        });
        return keyValuePairs.join('&');
    }

    const [paramvalues, setParamValues] = useState([]);
    
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { target: { value } } = event;
        setParamValues(
        typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        params[paramUrlName] = paramvalues.join();    
        setSearchParams(params);
        navigate(`${location.pathname}?${objectToQueryString(params)}`);
    }, 
    [paramvalues,searchParams]
    
    );


    return (
        <div>
        <FormControl sx={{ mb: 2, width: "100%" }}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">{cmpName}</InputLabel>
            <Select
            labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
            id="demo-multiple-name"
            multiple
            value={paramvalues}
            onChange={(event,id) => {
                handleChange(event,id);
            }}
            input={<OutlinedInput label={paramUrlName} notched />}
            renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(', ')}
            MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
            {arr?.map((lang) => (
                <MenuItem key={lang.code} value={lang.code}>
                    {lang.printname} ( {lang.count} )
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
        </div>  
    );
    };

    export default MultipleSelectList;
```

and i'm getting this of course:
[image: React MUI multi Select component]

Could there be a way to force `renderValue` to find the proper key in the array `arr` and render an array of `printname` values instead of `codes`?

in the handleChange function i also tried to intercept the `key` from `<MenuItem>` along with the `event` or adding a prop like `"id"={lang.code}` as well and pass it to the hook, but no success so far. Due to the async nature of `useState` a solution like that didn't work, it was either overwriting itself or losing sync with the correct selected (and rendered) ones. It seems that i need to use only the prop `value` from MenuItem in the handleChange for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

```
renderValue={(selected) => {
  const selectedLanguages = arr
    .filter((lang) => selected.includes(lang.code))
    .map((lang) => lang.printname);
  return selectedLanguages.join(', ');
}}
```

[image: example of a multiple mui react select component with rendered values different from the actual code values used in the hook state]